# I want to use the proper date function for the below given date which is hard coded in below Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below Oracle SQL query.

```
select p_name,
       cal_vale,
       St_val,
       l_date
from   pr_tab
where  L_date = to_date('03-sep-16','dd-mon-yy');
```

Here `03-Sep-16` is the hard coded date value,for capturing the last Saturday's data from database.

I don't want to use this hard coded value going forward.  I need some Oracle's inbuilt function to automate the process of getting the last Saturday's data from database.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: sysdate and next_day are already dates, so don't need the TO_DATE(...,'DD-MON-YY')

Comment: Re framing the question
I have the below Oracle SQL query.

select p_name,cal_vale,l_date from pr_tab where
  L_date = to_date('03-sep-16','dd-mon-yy');

Here 03-Sep-16 is the hard coded date value,for capturing the last Saturday's data from database.

I don't want to use this hard coded value going forward,instead want to use some Oracle SQL function ,which automate this process of capturing the last Saturday's data from database.

Comment: Hi Gary,I tired removing the to_date ....                                  TRUNC(L_date) =next_day((sysdate)-7,'SAT'),but still I didn't get the output as the hard coded value 03-sept-16

Comment: And what **is** the output you want? Don't just throw an isolated, incomplete line of code at us. Create a little example with sample data the actual output and the expected output (**[edit]** your question, don't post code in comments). And you should stay away from NLS dependent date formats. And ***never***, ever apply `to_date()` on a value that is already a `date`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`NEXT_DAY()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm#i78154):

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '8' DAY, 'SATURDAY' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

*(Note: you need to find the next Saturday from 8 days ago since, if today was Saturday, then if you found the next Saturday from 7 days ago you would be back to today.)*

Comment: Thank you for your response.SELECT next_day((sysdate)-7,'SAT') FROM DUAL ; also works for me.

Comment: @user1917985 If today is Saturday then `NEXT_DAY( SYSDATE - 7, 'SATURDAY' )` will return today and not last Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the date format specifier 'D', which specifies the day of the week, between 1 and 7 . One problem is that what Oracle returns depends on the NLS_TERRITORY setting, so it could be Sunday, Monday (or even Saturday I think).

Let's assume a value of 1 represents Sunday, like it does in North America.

For example, on a Thursday, to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'D')) returns 5.

`sysdate - to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'D'))` returns last Saturday's date for any day of the week.

This only works if the first day of the week (1) is a Sunday, according to the NLS_TERRITORY setting.

For example if 1 represents a Monday, then last Saturday is `sysdate - to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'D'))-1`

A better approach is to hard code the nls_date_language setting in the query, and get the day offset from the day *name*:

```
select case to_char (sysdate, 'FmDay', 'nls_date_language=english')
          when 'Monday' then 2
          when 'Tuesday' then 3
          when 'Wednesday' then 4
          when 'Thursday' then 5
          when 'Friday' then 6
          when 'Saturday' then 7
          when 'Sunday' then 1
       end d
  from dual
```

So

```
sysdate -case to_char (sysdate, 'FmDay', 'nls_date_language=english')
              when 'Monday' then 2
              when 'Tuesday' then 3
              when 'Wednesday' then 4
              when 'Thursday' then 5
              when 'Friday' then 6
              when 'Saturday' then 7
              when 'Sunday' then 1
           end
```

reliably gives you last Saturday's date  for any day of the week, regardless of NLS settings.

Comment: Thanks Tony for the help.Let me try this

Comment: No problem, make sure to approve answer when it works.

Comment: Hi Tony, it works in my query to get the last Saturday's data :) Thank you again for the help